# Suggestions for a new laptop

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, processor

I am planning to buy new laptop. Need some suggestions from you guys.

Here is some details:

- I'm a web developer
- I'll use it for productivity and multi - tasking (running php server + mysql, open 2 or 3 different web browsers with several tabs, some word, excel and pdf files, at least two IDE's, google meet at same time...)
- I'll use the laptop to work with general development, maybe android studio will be included
- I work from home, so portability and battery life are not my priority, but they are some kind of nice to have

I have two in mind:

**DELL G15 5530($1080)**

```
Processor: Intel Core i7-13650hx
Ram: 8GB DDR5 4800Mhz
Storage: SSD 1TB M.2 PCI-Express NVMe
Dedicated Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4050 6GB GDDR6
```

**Lenovo LOQ 15($934)**

```
Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 7840HS
Ram: 8GB DDR5 5600MHz
Storage: SSD 512GB M.2 PCI-Express NVMe
Dedicated Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4050 6GB GDDR6
```

I'm a little wary of AMD, as I've always used Intel. But LOQ is a laptop that I liked, and it seems to have an "unique" power management and a good keyboard. The i7 versions of LOQ are expensives.

Some days ago, I had decided to buy this one, but "changed" my mind(I was confused by the two others):

**Dell Vostro 7620($1025)**

```
Processor: Intel Core i7-12700H
Ram: 40GB DDR5 4800MHz
Storage: SSD 1TB M.2 PCI-Express NVMe
Dedicated Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti, 4GB GDDR6
```

Well, my current laptop is an ASUS ux305ca, and I know that any of these laptops will be a lot more powerful than mine, but I'm planning to keep the new laptop for, at least, the next 5~6 years.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Are you normally connecting to an external monitor or just use laptop's own display? If you normally work with the built-in display, you may want to check out the ones with screens bigger than 15".

Comment: Yes, I use an external 32" curved monitor ;)

Answer (score 0):

Those top 2 laptops only have 8GB of RAM. Assuming one of the IDEs you use is a Jetbrains IDE, only that one can take up half of that RAM. Your original idea is much better looking at the base specs since for multitasking you definetly need a lot of RAM. When it comes to CPU, all of them are good, and for GPU, all of them are overpowered. For storage, 1TB is nice to have but you can't store the entire production database on there (but you should never use a developer's laptop in production so that's probably not a problem)

And about AMD, don't be wary about them, they are part of the reason why CPU performance numbers have increased a lot and are still a good option

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm currently using Visual Studio Code and Sublime Text the most. Let's assume that I'm going to upgrade RAM, from 8 to 24GB(with 16GB $53) or 40GB(with 32GB $93), just after purchase, is it worth for any of these two models?

Comment: Then from what I can think off the top of my head all of these are pretty good, but you will have to check that the RAM is upgradable

Comment: Cool, I noticed that Lenovo can only be upgraded to 32GB 5600mhz(and 1TB ssd max storage, even with 2x m.2 slots, I don't know why). Dell G15 has some videos on YouTube upgrading to 64GB 4800mhz. As my current laptop has only 8GB and freezes a lot, I don't know if I will need more than 32 GB of RAM and if the RAM frequency would change anything for me. Still not sure which one to choose